What are the "white dot" icons turning into diamonds at the right of control in array modifier
This is a very newcomer question, and I'm probably missing the vocabulary, since pasting the keywords of my question in search engines leads to nowhere(*)...
Here is my issued.
Following a tutorial on array modifiers, I accidentally clicked on the white dot located at the right of most controls, for example Count. This turns the white dot into a hollow  diamond and the control background becomes green. See screenshot: 
I've no idea what purpose these dots and diamonds serve, but I noticed that:

this locks the changes to the control field (in fact I can only change it value transiently before it gets reverted)
I did't find how to disable this "diamond lock": clicking on the diamond doesn't change it back to a dot!

The dots are indeed present in the screenshots in the array modifier page of the manual, but are not discussed unless I missed something.
So I'll be glad to get some feedback (perhaps I only need a clue about the name of this dot/diamond feature). Or perhaps I got hit by an UI bug (I'm thinking here of the difficulty to disable the "diamond lock"). I'm using Blender 4.1 on Debian stable.
(*) a web search for "white dot icon issued" leads to discussions about specular dots... while "diamond icon" leads tutorials on how to model a diamond...

The green backgrounds mean that you've added an animation keyframe to the value which you do by clicking on the dot. To remove it, right-click on the field and choose 'Delete keyframe' or hover the mouse over the field and hit Alt-I.
